# Getting unexpected values in the Pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

When displaying the "greatest" values to the console I found that it changes if I uncomment the last line. Moreover, it changes to a value (1709.99) that was neither in `longStop` nor in `longStop` before. Where could it come from?

Screenshot without the last line:

[image: screenshot without the last line]

Screenshot with last line:

[image: screenshot with last line]

Here is my small script:

```
//@version=4

strategy("CE", shorttitle="CE", overlay=true)

length = input(title="ATR P", type=input.integer, defval=22)
mult = input(title="ATR M", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0)

atr = mult * atr(length)

// debug = label.new(x = bar_index, y = close, style = label.style_label_left, text = stri)
// label.delete(debug[1])

// plot(atr, color=color.yellow, linewidth=1)
// plotchar(bar_index, "Bar Index", "", location = location.top)

longStop = highest(close, length) - atr
// /plot(close[1] - mult * atr(length)[1], title = "longStopPrev", color=color.blue, linewidth=1)
longStopPrev = longStop[1]
plotchar(longStop, "longStop", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(longStopPrev, "longStopPrev", "", location = location.top)
greatest =  max(longStop, longStopPrev)
// plot(greatest, title = "greatest", color=color.blue, linewidth=1)
plotchar(greatest, "greatest", "", location = location.top)
longStop := close[1] > longStopPrev ? greatest : longStop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`longStop` is of type `series`. That means, it will have historical data for each bar.

With your last line, you change the value of `longStop` depending on your condition.

Then on the next execution, you have this statement: `longStopPrev = longStop[1]`. Here you access `longStop`'s previous value.

So, what's happening here is, with your last line, you change `longStop`'s value and therefore `longStop[1]` returns a different value on the next execution.